# Raspberry Pi and Ada Compiler (gnat on Raspbian) - GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3, software-compilation, ada

I am looking for programming examples written in Ada (gnat) to access GPIO.
I just started using a RPi3 with Raspbian, works fine. Then installed the gnat compiler and my first programs (simple tests with textual input/output via console) compile/link and execute fine.
Now I want to access the GPIO.
Any suggestions ?
PS: Don't suggest to use another programming language :)
I want to learn Ada and I have experience in programming in COBOL on BS2000, MS-Visual Basic on Windows, C on Solaris and Arduino, and some more...

Comment: FYI: I have no experience with ADA, except from the usual helloworld and some basic console and file IO test programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll mention my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library and [daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) as the daemon was designed partly with other language use in mind.

You can manipulate the GPIOs from Ada by using the [socket](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/sif.html) interface.

If you want a pure Ada interface have a look at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_tiny_gpio which shows the sort of code you'll need to port to Ada.

Comment: Hi joan. 
Just peeped into tiny_gpio.c and will run it on my Pi 3 soon. I hope to start translating to ADA next week (and adapt hardware revision). 
My Pi is a hobby project :)
Thanks for the swift response to my question.

Comment: Hello, @Joan Can your library handle the [Onion Omega2](https://onion.io/omega2/) ? See [here](https://docs.onion.io/omega2-project-book-vol1/omega2-intro.html) for GPIO. If not, can I use the socket interface? I m new to this stuff :-/

Comment: Hmm, it seems like it has an [Arduino hat](https://docs.onion.io/omega2-docs/arduino-dock-2.html), so no doubt soon also a Pi hat. But I would still prefer not to use a hat (shield) if possible